# Corona invalid apk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

When ever I try and install my complied project mad with corona to my android device with adb. I get an error message saying "invalid apk". Has any one got any idea of what is causing this and if so how to fix it?

Comment: whate android device, what android version, come on...

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo with android 4.3 installed

Comment: If you are using Android Studio you need to put the error messages here. It is generally signing or permissions issues. Have you installed from anywhere else?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using corona to make my app. Sometimes it seems to work and sometimes not. Though it always will install on bluestacks simulator. Thanks